# Not able to call component from navbar component html in angular

Tags: angular, components, navbar, angular-router

I have created a navbar and i am trying to call component of other module so that i will be able to access different pages from navbar links.
I have used routerlink as an attribute to call the components. Hereby is the code for better understanding.

navbar.component.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
<li><a routerlink="/fixeddeposits" routerLinkActive="active">Link</a></li>
```

navbar.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TableComponent } from '../table/table.component';
import { FixedDepositsComponent } from '../fixed-deposits/fixed- 
deposits.component';

const routes: Routes = [

{path: 'table', component: TableComponent},
{path: 'fixeddeposits', component: FixedDepositsComponent},
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class NavbarRoutingModule { }
export const routedComponents = [
TableComponent,
FixedDepositsComponent,
];
```

navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component,NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarModule } from './navbar.module';
 @NgModule({ 
 imports:[NavbarModule],
  })   
 @Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'navbar',
  templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html'
  })

  export class NavbarComponent {
   title = 'app'; 
   }
```

navbar.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavbarRoutingModule, routedComponents } from 
 './navbar.routing.module';

 @NgModule({
   imports: [   
   NavbarRoutingModule,],
   declarations: [
    routedComponents,
   ],
   })
 export class NavbarModule { }
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TableComponent } from './table/table.component';
import { FixedDepositsComponent } from './fixed-deposits/fixed-d 
eposits.component';

const routes: Routes = [

{path: 'table', component: TableComponent},
{path: 'fixeddeposits', component: FixedDepositsComponent},
];
 @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
  })
 export class AppRoutingModule {}

 export const routingComponents = [TableComponent, FixedDepositsComponent];
```

When i use this code i am not getting error but when i click the navbar button link i am not redirected to fixed deposit component.

Comment: Can you add the fixed deposit module to `imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],`?  If you wan to use lazy loading, then, you may want to go through https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules and understand the examples.

Comment: Can you post the definition of main routes ?

Comment: @AdrianFâciu i have tried doing the same in main routes, i have mentioned the code above for app.routing.ts

Comment: @WandMaker Do i need to add fixeddeposit module because i didnt create module for it because i am looking to access the fixed deposits component by defining it into the routes this way : {path: 'fixeddeposits', component: FixedDepositsComponent},

Comment: You can create a stackblitz version of your app - then, someone can take a look

Comment: I framed the code into the stackblitz, here is the Link for stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i1mvx7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

routing files shouldn't be separate modules and there were some syntax errors like small l in 'routerlink' => routerLink.

Updated your code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptzpjs?file=src/app/app.routing.ts

[**Angular Lazy Loading**](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: I tried doing the above mentioned changes, didnt workout for me, when i click on the button there isnt any error but it is not redirected to the other component.

Comment: Here is the link for my code:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i1mvx7

Comment: You pointed out the mistake of "routerLink" and now i am clear with the concept of routing. Thank you so much, your efforts really helped !

Comment: Oh I tried to up vote your answer but as my reputation is below 15 I am not able to!  I will surely do as soon as possible